# Change device information in Android on virtual box

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-x86

I have installed Android X86 4.3 on virtual box with system set as usb tablet. I also have bluestacks emulator. If I try to install some apps from play store , I get error "your device isn't compatible with this version" on virtual box. But they work absolutely fine on bluestacks emu. 
Anyway to change device info?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that Google play services is installed for the corresponding target ABI used in the emulator. [image: As shown in the image here]